# Echo <?php ?> in echo

Tags: php

Is it possible to output `<?php ?>` output in echo? So the situation is this:

```
<?php
  // some code
  foreach ( $something as $row )
  {
     echo '<input type="hidden" id="'.$row["id"].'" value="<?php echo $cats; ?>">'
  }
 ?>
```

So how to output `$cats` in the value php part? Is it possible at all?
I need the value that `$cats` hold not the whole part whit `htmlentities`

edit:

It is not duplicate and it is not `'.$cats.'` may be it's my fold that I didn't explain properly.

`$cats` got its value from response of ajax script not from this query

Comment: Use echo '<input type="hidden" id="'.$row["id"].'" value='".$cats."'>'

Comment: Php quotes inside php quote!!! also echo inside echo!!

Comment: In that case you need to execute a manual entity conversion: < becomes &lt; and > becomes &gt; Change those 2 characters and it will work.

Comment: @Blaatpraat this is what `htmlentities` do. As I said I don't need this.. Thank's anyway.

Comment: Your question is still unclair, even after your update.

Comment: This question is so lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need of that tag again. Simply concatenate the variable -

```
echo '<input type="hidden" id="'.$row["id"].'" value="' . $cats . '">'
```

**Update**

With **jQuery** -

```
var response = "The response after ajax request";
$('input[type="hidden"]').val(response); // Selector will depend on your code
```

Comment: I need it because it is come from another part of script.. so with `'.$cats.'` I get `value="0"`

Comment: There is some response from ajax ..

Comment: You want that response to be set as value of the input?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying

Comment: Then why are you using `PHP` if you want to set value with `javascript`?

Comment: I don't know how in `javascript` and ... it seems also in `php`..

Comment: Check the update and read about jquery. Will help you a lot.

Comment: Ok, I think this can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already in a PHP block, you don't need to open new php tags.

Try this instead.

```
<?php
  // some code
  foreach ( $something as $row )
  {
     echo '<input type="hidden" id="'.$row["id"].'" value="'.$cats.'">'
}?>
```